# Local SqlServer 2016 - Login failed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database-connection

can you help me? I need connect to my local database on SqlServer 2016 but when I try open connection, I got this error. I do not try other ways to login because I do not remember password (i always use windows auth.)

> Additional information: Cannot open database "My_Project" requested
>   by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-C448DNE\Denis'.

Here is my c# code which I use:

```
public class DbHelper
{
    public SqlConnection Connection { get; private set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }

    public DbHelper()
    {
        Connection = new SqlConnection();
        Language = "en";
    }

    public bool Connect(string conString)
    {
        if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Connection.ConnectionString = conString;
            Connection.Open();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool Connect()
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = My_Project; Integrated Security=true;";

        return Connect(connString);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        Connection.Close();
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
    {
        int rowNumber = 0;
        try
        {
            rowNumber = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        return rowNumber;
    }
}
```

And here I use this class:

```
    ...
    private DbHelper _db;

    public SqlEmployeeMapper()
    {
        _db = new DbHelper();
    }

    public int Create(Employee entity)
    {
        var conn = _db.Connect();

        string queryString = "insert into \"employees\" (first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, password, city, address, holiday, role_id, departmant_id)" +
            "values(@first_name, @last_name, @email, @phone_number, @password, @city, @address, @holiday, @role_id, @departmant_id);";


        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString);
        PrepareCommand(command, entity);
        var id = _db.ExecuteNonQuery(command);

        _db.Close();

        return id;
    }
...
```

EDIT:
I try open Server explorer in VS2015 and click "Add connection" ... I enter "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" as Server name, and when I open dropdown list with databases, do not see my databases

Comment: Do you have SSMS installed?  If so can you connect via that?

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a login for your WIndows account

Comment: @destination-data yes SSMS  works fine

Comment: @stuartd do you mean this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, `CREATE LOGIN … FROM WINDOWS` but if you can log in and view the database via SSMS you must already have access..

Comment: Not entirely sure how the whitespace in the connection string will be interpreted.  Possible that `Initial Catalog = My_Project` is read as [ My_Project].  Can you try `Initial Catalog=My_Project` instead?

Comment: @destination-data still not works but I think it is good way, because I have other one error "Additional information: Cannot open database "My_Project" requested by the login. The login failed."

Answer (score 0):

Instances of SQL Local Db have a name and an instance named pipe.  When using .Net below 4.0.2 you have to connect via the named pipe.  From the [docs on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Troubleshooting):

> If your application uses a version of .NET before 4.0.2 you must connect directly to the named pipe of the LocalDB. The Instance pipe name value is the named pipe that the instance of LocalDB is listening on. The portion of the Instance pipe name after LOCALDB# will change each time the instance of LocalDB is started. To connect to the instance of LocalDB by using SQL Server Management Studio, type the Instance pipe name in the Server name box of the Connect to Database Engine dialog box. From your custom program you can establish connection to the instance of LocalDB using a connection string similar to SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=np:\.\pipe\LOCALDB#F365A78E\tsql\query");

Unlike the name, the named pipe changes every time the instance is restarted.  One way to find the current named pipe is via the command line.

```
SQLLocalDb i MSSQLLocalDb
```

If the instance has stopped you'll need to start it.  Starting the instance will generate the named pipe.  Five minutes or more without a connection will stop the instance.

```
SQLLocalDb s MSSQLLcoalDb
```

For more on the command line take a peek at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh247716.aspx), again taken from MSDN.

I'm not sure if the big changes in [SS 2016 SP1](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql+server+2016+sp1&tbm=nws) will remove the need to connect via named pipe.

Comment: I use .net 4.5 :/

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Visual Studio?  If so, can you create a connection in the Server Explorer that authenticates successfully?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question and should be a comment

Comment: Your connection string uses "(localdb)" which uses a localdb installation.  If you have SQL Server 2016 installed containing your target DB, you will not find it using (localdb).  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database/.  Assuming your SQL 2016 instance is named, MSSQLLocalDB, try connecting to it directly without the (localdb).

Comment: I tried this, and I have this error "
Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL "